# Xamarin iOS APNs Different Payload

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, push-notification

I am working on a iOS version of Xamarin application (android was built by another person). I have used [Plugin.FirebasePushNotifications](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) plugin and have successfully set up the apns from Firebase console. The response looks something like this:

```
2020-09-28 12:50:57.566 Project.iOS[16900:2364597] {
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "This is the body of the notitification";
            title = "Testing Notification";
        };
        "mutable-content" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = 1601286657133844;
    "gcm.notification.sound2" = default;
    "google.c.sender.id" = 633381035766;
}
```

The notifications successfully arrives on the device and it works perfectly in foreground/background/app killed.

However, when I use different server with different protocol(?) I receive this type of message:

```
2020-09-28 12:51:30.944 SycretBeauty.iOS[16900:2364597] {
    Body = "\U0422\U0415\U0421\U0422 8";
    Title = "Title";
    aps =     {
        "content-available" = 1;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = 1601286690545984;
}
```

The id is the same and I receive it ok in VS console. However, the notification doesn't pop up on the screen. What should I do to see the notification popping up on the screen? I can't change the API and Android is already all set up working with that type of response structure...

(and I don't even know why "TEST 8" shows in UNICODE characters...)

Comment: You could post the issue on the github project site https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues .

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by downstreaming through Postman.

Url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Headers(2):

ContentType - application/json

Authorization - `<your server key from firebase>`

Body:

```
{     "to":"d8bEmMpQJE6EuEYCG4COKq:APA91bG7YCDT7AyyJGS3j5bnpwVrbvSgdrjuUcatjOBLSkKaGpa2xZP7YDhzMAEMYfLDDp7gTgzUzhx-vs4nvr_n3yJQ6FdU9m0sxxw-stzHIxtuvXEPSXNHGy_2yxWBxGLn0IVktsil",
        "notification" : {
        "Body" : "Notification Body",
        "Title" : "Notification Title",
        "content_available" : true,
        "priority" : "high"
        }
    }
```

The notification arrives after I use correct syntax for "body" and "title" all the time.